# Screen is black, but connected according to xrandr

Tags: multiple-monitors, 17.04, hdmi, xrandr

I have some trouble with my HDMI Display.

xrandr output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 5760 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

HDMI-A-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DVI-D-0 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DVI-I-1 connected 1920x1080+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      70.07    60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   640x480       66.67    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

The monitor that is black (HDMI-A-0) is connected, and have the right position. But still, it's all black. It works fine when I boot up. But then it just goes black.

The two working monitors have workspace 2 and 3, so it feels that the system show how assigned workspace 1 to the black screen.

Any ides?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `xrandr -q`to see all modes and rates.

Then use `xrandr --output *name of display* --mode *resolution* --rate *frame rate*`to set both frame-rate and mode. The problem was the rate for me.

Comment: Where did you do this? Can you tell us, cause I have a TV that has this same behaviour

Comment: I used xrandr --mode command. Check the --rate command also.

Comment: Edit your answer, I wiill test. So, I'll vote It.

Comment: my problem resolved by using --rate frame.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I am having a similar problem,  display goes blank, but xrandr shows it connected

But found that if I tell xrandr make any sort of change (it must be a change) then the display is reset and it all comes back.

For example, have xrandr turn it off and on...

```
  xrandr --output DP-1-1 --off
  xrandr --output DP-1-1 --auto
```

However it losses its position information and just becomes a clone, until I again reset the position.    Any windows on that display get moved to make them at least partially visible in the other display, though I have found it shift a LOT of windows which should not have been effected too.  Basically it is a horrible fix.

This fixes the problem some of the time...

```
  xset dpms force suspend # or standby or off (same result)
  xset dpms force on
```

This is the best solution I found so far, but depends on your setup...

Move the display just a little (one pixel), then moving it back!
It is enough of a change to get xrandr to resurect the monitor and does not cause my application windows to suddenly change position.

```
  xrandr --output DP-1-2 --pos 1921x0;    # shift one pixel
  xrandr --output DP-1-2 --pos 1920x0;    # shift it back
```